# Django Update AbstractUser

Tags: django, heroku

```
IntegrityError at /
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_profile.username
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_profile.username
```

**How do I update an abstractuser from a post request using a form that's already signed in?**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import UserProfileForm
from .models import Profile

def index(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            img = form.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
            obj, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
                username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                defaults={'avatar': img},
            )
            obj.save()
            print(obj)
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
    context['form']= form
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='home'), 
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='',null=True, blank=True )
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

from pages.models import Profile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('avatar',)
```

Comment: can you check if you ```username``` is being sent from frontend or not.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: ```NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_profile.username
``` it says you are trying to send null value.

Comment: How would I check?

Comment: You don't have to check, it's telling you the username is empty.  You can print `form.cleaned_data` to see what's actually being received.

Comment: print(form.cleaned_data.get('username')) gives none and print(request.user) give AnonymousUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import UserProfileForm
from .models import Profile

def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            """ 
            img = form.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
            print(img)
            print(form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
            print(request.user)
            obj, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
                username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                defaults={'avatar': img},
            )
            obj.save()
            print(obj)
            """
            form.save()
            return redirect('home') 
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    context['form']= form
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

I swapped it to this and it just works but it doesn't delete the old photo in the s3 bucket yet. It was instance=request.user which was needed.